# How do I keep all my bazaar branches in multiple physical locations?

Tags: git, version-control, bazaar

I've recently started working on a project that uses bazaar. I'm attempting to find a bazaar workflow I like, and being a regular git user I can't avoid using git as a reference point.

In git, all my branches are stored in the one directory. If a branch lasts longer than a working day, I "git push  " to keep a copy on the server. Keeping the branch on my local machine only makes me nervous.

With bazaar, I'm currently using a shared repository layout that looks like so:

```
project/
  trunk/
  branch1/
  branch2/
```

trunk is a pristine checkout of the upstream repo, and the branches are my local feature branches (created with "bzr clone trunk branch1"). When a branch is ready, I cd into trunk and run "bzr merge ../branch1", commit the merge, then "bzr push" to push changes into upstream.

This works fairly well, but I'd like to keep branchN in more places. In case my laptop dies, I'm hit by a bus, etc.

Is there common way bazaar users do this? Should I just rsync the entire dir somewhere? should I "bzr push " from each branch before I go home at night? Is my fundamental approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong in any case. I don't recommend to rsync entire dir, but instead using bzr push in each branch. There is also exists [repo-push](https://launchpad.net/bzr-repo-push) plugin that can mirror entire shared repo with all its branches to another location, maybe this is what you need to simplify your workflow.